# Str Object Error in simple Python Code

Tags: python, string, bash, unix, terminal

I'm trying echo a user's input, then echo it again in both uppercase and lowercase.  I receive this instead of my expected output:

```
<built-in method lower of str object at 0x100e205a0>
```

What does that mean?

I'm using this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

phrase = raw_input("Enter a phrase to be capitalized: ")
print phrase
print phrase.lower
print phrase.lower
```

Comment: You need to _call_ functions.  `phrase.lower()`.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like you simply need to add `()` to the end of your function calls.  When you type `print phrase.lower` the Python interpreter is giving you back a description of the function object.  If you instead do `print phrase.lower()` it will print the result of applying the function to `phrase`.  Like most things in Python, functions are objects.

Comment: Cool, thanks!So I added the () and this time I got a diff error-          File "<stdin>", line 1
    python force.py

Comment: hmmm, works in my Python interpreter.  can you edit your question to include all the output?